# How to install atmosphere packages without meteorite?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

mrt currently has a bug with spaces in Volume names on the Mac https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/172.

Until that is fixed, how can I manually install packages from atmosphere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a directory called `/packages` in your project & then manually install each package and its dependencies. e.g for 'meteor router'

in `/packages`

```
git clone https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git
mv meteor-router router

git clone --recursive https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git
mv meteor-page-js-ie-support page-js-ie-support
```

The second is a dependency on meteor router which you can see on the package's [atmosphere page](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router). It's recursive to make sure the submodule pages-js is also git cloned in.

**Meteor 0.65+**

As pointed out by thatjuan: Once you do this, you just need to add the main one to your project. You don't have to add the dependencies.

```
meteor add router
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, don't i also need to add some entries to a packages.json? I'm sure I read this somewhere but I just can't remember where.

Comment: i tried it and it worked! but how did you know to rename the files as you did? what if i'm installing another package, how would i know to rename the files and to what filenames? there was no indication in the  readme on the github entry for meteor-router to rename as such.

Comment: You wouldn't have to edit the smart.json or anything, you don't need meteorite to use the above & it ignores these files too, meaning you can use it on windows too. You have to rename the directory to whatever the package's name is on atmosphere

Comment: I found that after 0.6.5 you also have to add the package to .meteor/packages (using meteor add). I was trying with iron-router, and this was the only way to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

meteor router also needs HTML5-History-API

git clone --recursive https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git

remove **meteor** and the folder should look like this **HTML5-History-API**

then **meteor add router**