# meteor: meteorite how to convert an in-use package that has been removed from atmosphere into a locally commitable package

Tags: git, meteor, meteorite

I am using a typeahead-js atmosphere package in my app but it was deleted from atmosphere and github by the owner (since it was deprecated). Now running meteor complains. I don't want to convert to the new typeahead stuff at the moment and would rather use the package as is.

I have the files still in my packages folder so I need to know how to convert the package to be a local package that is stored in git. This: [How to install atmosphere packages without meteorite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159924/how-to-install-atmosphere-packages-without-meteorite) explains how to make local changes by cloning the repo out of github but I believe the original package still needs to be on atmosphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I forgot was that packages installed from atmosphere are actually downloaded to your local /home/user/.meteorite/packages (at least in ubuntu.) Your project/packages folder just has symlinks to the locations for each installed package. With that in mind the steps are:

1. Copy the files from the symlinked package folder
2. Remove the symlink and add a folder with the symlinks name
3. Paste the files into that folder
4. temporarily remove the /packages folder from the project's root .gitignore file
5. add the packages .build directory to the .gitignore e.g. packages/typeahead-js/.build
6. use git to add the package you copied over restore /packages to the project's root .gitignore file
7. modify the projects smart.json to include the local path to the package e.g:

'

```
{
  "packages": {
    "typeahead-js": {
      "path": "/packages/typeahead-js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Meteorite lets you point to a local package. Just change the typeahead entry in your `smart.json` to look like this:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "typeahead-js": {
      "path": "../../path/to/local/typeahead-js"
    }
  }
}
```

[More info here](http://collidercreative.com/adding-custom-local-packages-to-meteor-with-meteorite/)

Alternatively, github and atmosphere are free services. Depending on the license you could release your own fork.

Comment: This gets us almost there, but there is still something missing to allow it to be committed locally in git. The steps so far: 1) The package is deleted from atmosphere. 2) Get a local error when running meteor 3) Add /packages/typeahead-js to the path in smart.json 4) do ??? to add the package to git... I have tried removing it from the top-level and lower level .gitignore files but it still doesn't show up to be added in git... do I need to force it in some way?

Comment: thanks for your answer, it definitely was a component to the overall solution