# How to add a Meteor package manually

Tags: meteor

I have created a Meteor (version 0.8.3 for Windows) hello world app:

```
meteor create helloworld
cd helloworld
```

My proxy does not allow me to use `meteor add`, so I'm trying manually installation. Then, I created a packages folder inside the helloworld folder:

```
md packages
```

I downloaded master from boostrap package `Github` into a zip from the `Github` website, and unziped inside packages. Modified the name of the zipepr folder from `bootstrap-master` to `bootstrap`.

Then tried:

```
meteor add boostrap
```

And this is the output:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

 => Errors while parsing arguments:

While adding package bootstrap:
error: no such package

Your package catalog may be out of date.
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi ! did you solve this problem ? I have the same right now ..

Comment: @Benobab I tried following Bird's answer, but it is difficult depending on the package because you have to also install each dependency manually. Not every package is available at its latest version for manual installation. Meteor is just not designed for its usage in an enterprise with stupid proxy policies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

meteor packages should have a `package.js` file.And you can find package name in `Package.describe`. Then use `meteor add package-name` to add package locally

Comment: I guess you mean package.json. Inside it says "name": "boostrap", which is the name I'm currently trying to use

Comment: The official bootstrap meteor package as of v1.0 -> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/

Comment: The bootstrap you downloaded from github is not a meteor package.I find a bootstrap package [here](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3),but not up to date.

Comment: I see. I found a couple implementations not up to date such as https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-bootstrap-3/. In both of them, it recomended going to the updated package in atmosphere, and the github link there is the one I provided. I guess it's a broken link problem at atmosphere then. How can I find the package then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a git clone of github package instead of a zip file ...

Source : [How to install atmosphere packages without meteorite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159924/how-to-install-atmosphere-packages-without-meteorite)