# Meteor - importing jsPDF without atmosphere

Tags: javascript, meteor, jspdf

In the beginning I wanted the option of being able to add different fonts into the generated pdf file. The answer for that was found here in StackOverFlow, however, if I had added jsPDF through atmosphere using the cli command "meteor add jsPDF:core" I could not edit the files as they would be regenerated and therefore written over (jspdf.js file somewhere stashed in meteors file structures).

Therefore, I tried to import jsPDF the normal way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
```

(jQuery is already included with meteor).

I then try to run my code

```
doc.save('hello.pdf');
```

and get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined"
```

from `jspdf.js`

This error did not occur when I had installed jsPDF through meteor (reason I want it manually is to edit the jsPDF files).

Answer (score 0):

Importing packages with jQuery is not the preferred way in Meteor. Instead you could follow these steps.

Create a directory packages in your project.

Clone the library in /packages

```
git clone https://github.com/michaelbishop/meteor-jsPDF.git
mv meteor-jsPDF jspdf
```

Then you can add this package manually to your project and edit the files you want:

```
meteor add jspdf
```

Stackoverflow discussion about adding packages manually: [How to install atmosphere packages without meteorite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159924/how-to-install-atmosphere-packages-without-meteorite)

Comment: Thanks! Started to move to that direction. However, when you package stuff to atmosphere it has to be done differently than just the available git packages that you posted?

So I googled up the same name as the atmosphere package called jsPDF:core and it was on this github adress https://github.com/MeteorPackaging/jspdf-core-wrapper

However this does not include the jsPDF package itself. So my question now is if I need to "rewrite" something in the original jsPDF package (except my own modifications) to be able to install it myself to meteor?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry I saw now it was a different link. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem!

If someone is writing stuff for the jspdf.js file and need to do changes. One must go into dist/jspdf.debug.js and edit that one.